# How to show if a camera is online with the nest api

Tags: nest-api

I'm working on a website that contains multiple Nest cameras and I wonder if it is possible to display if a camera is online before a user clicks on the link to view this cam.

I would do it with a XMLRequest in javascript but I cant find how to do it.

Comment: For interacting with the user's Camera, you will likely need to request permissions (similar to requesting permission to get user's location, etc.)

You should take a look at the **Camera API**:

(http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Camera_API)

For person-to-person Audio/Video sharing, check out **WebRTC API**

(http://www.webrtc.org/web-apis/development)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API)

Answer (score 0):

You would make a REST call for it, HTTP GET specifically. The request url would look like this:

```
https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/cameras/<device_id>/is_online?auth=<auth_token>
```

Using cURL it would look like this:

```
curl -v -L -H 
"Authorization: Bearer <auth_token>" 
-X GET "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/cameras/<device_id>/is_online"
```

Reference: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#cameras